# How can I resolve Error 500 when deploying a Node.js application on cPanel?

Tags: node.js, deployment, cors, cpanel, http-status-code-500

Hello :) I'm trying to solve a problem with my node application. In development, I have no worries, everything is functional. I wanted to deploy my application via CPANEL and I did a test route to verify that the application works.

This returns me a status of 500 with the message: "Internal Server Error".

I checked my server.js file and I don't understand where the problem comes from. When I make a request from the front, I also get this message: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://cinefilmsnodeserver.cinefilms.fr/api/check' from origin 'http://home.cinefilms.fr' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

The cors headers are however defined in my server.js file

Here is the file code:

```
const express = require("express");
const postRoutes = require("./routes/post.routes");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/user.routes");
require("dotenv").config();
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/test-no-cors", (req, res) => {

  res.status(200).json({ message: "API connected successfully" });
});

const allowOrigins = [process.env.CLIENT_URL];

app. use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.headers.origin && allowOrigins.includes(req.headers.origin)) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.headers.origin);
  } else {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "null");
  }
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  next();
});

app. use("/api", userRoutes);
app. use("/api/post", postRoutes);

app. listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});`
```

thank you in advance for your help

I hope I can deploy my nodejs application

Comment: Never allow the `null` origin; doing so is insecure. Also, instead of implementing CORS by hand, use a [CORS middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the "/test-no-cors route" is defined before the CORS middleware, so your CORS policy middleware isn't applied to it.
To apply the CORS policy to all routes, define the CORS middleware before any routes are defined.

Here's the corrected code:

```
const express = require("express");
const postRoutes = require("./routes/post.routes");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/user.routes");
require("dotenv").config();
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(express.json());

const allowOrigins = [process.env.CLIENT_URL];

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.headers.origin && allowOrigins.includes(req.headers.origin)) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.headers.origin);
  } else {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "null");
  }
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  next();
});

app.get("/test-no-cors", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ message: "API connected successfully" });
});

app.use("/api", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/post", postRoutes);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: Hi Arsalan, Thank you for your feedback, It's voluntary, I wanted to test the route without the horns because none of my routes work. here are the server logs.
37.66.161.157 - - [25/May/2023:08:45:07 +0200] "GET /test-no-cors HTTP/1.1 "500686" - ""Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
37.66.161.157 - - [25/May/2023:09:02:08 +0200] "GET /api/check HTTP/1.1" 500 686 "http://home.cinefilms.fr/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"